# How do I use the Intermediate Value Theorem in this proof?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I'm trying to prove that for any continuous function $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ there must be some $a$ such that $a = f(a)$.

Since I'm new to real analysis, I'm having trouble deciding how formal \ detailed my proofs have to be. At first I felt like this is a valid proof:

For contradiction, assume there is a function $f$ for which there is no $a$ such that $a = f(a)$. Then $f(0) \neq 0$ so $f(0) > 0$. Every $f(x)$ must be bounded below by $x$ ***(or else it intersects the diagonal $f(x)=x$ contrary to assumption)*** and bounded above by $1$. Then we get the absurdity $1 < f(1) < 1$.

I realized that this proof lacks rigor in the bolded part. Intuitively it makes sense that if a function has $f(0) > 0$ and $f(a) <a $ (equivalent to "$f(a)$ is not bounded below by $a$") for some $a$, then the function will cross the diagonal $f(x) = x$ somewhere.

But I need the Intermediate Value Theorem to *prove* this. I'm not sure how to use the Intermediate Value Theorem to prove that a function will intersect $f(x) = x$, and that is what I need help with.

Comment: If you really wanted you could say "The result follows immediately from Brouwer's fixed point theorem."

Comment: Oh, this exercise in Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis introduced fixed points, so I guess this is Pugh's way of asking students to prove Brouwer's fixed point theorem.

Comment: It's silly to invoke Brouwer's fixed-point theorem here, because that is a significantly deeper result than the one that we want to prove.

Comment: That's why it was more for a kick then an actual hint.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof looks really good. Since you are worried about the claim with the bolded part you could say this. Consider the function $g(x):=f(x)-x$. This is a continuous function as well. Since $f(0)>0$ we have $g(0)>0$. If at any point $g(x)<0$ then the intermediate value theorem gives a $c$ such that $g(c)=0$. This would mean $f(c)-c=0 \implies f(c)=c$. Thus $f(x)>x$ always.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the Intermediate Value Theorem to the function $h(x)=f(x)-x$: $h(0) \ge 0$ and $h(1) \le 0$, so there exists $c \in [0,1]$ such that $h(c)=0$.